# How do I open json file from resx file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have resources.resx file and I have resources folder. I'm trying to get one json file from it.

project structure: [image: project structure]

**code I have**

```
string resxFile = @".\resources.resx";
using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(resxFile)) {
                
                using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse((FileStream)resxSet.GetObject("allCivs"))) {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

I get this error:[image: error screen]

As far as I understand, I am not correctly specifying the path to the "resx" file, because the program tries to find this file in the "bin" folder.

**How can I correctly specify the path to it? Are my further actions for reading the json file correct?**

**EDIT:**

data inside allCivs.json(just two elements,there are 43 like those):

```
"Austria": {
        "Лидер": [
            {
                "image": "civStuffIcons/Австрия_Лидер1.png",
                "Мария Терезия": {
                    "Персоналия": "Дипломатическая уния:Позволяет тратить  золото на то, чтобы присоединять или делать сателлитами города-государства, которые оставались вашими союзниками 5 и более ходов."
                }
            }
        ],
        "Уникальный юнит": [
            {
                "image": "civStuffIcons/Австрия_Уникальный юнит1.png",
                "Гусар": {
                    "Эпоха": "Новейшее время",
                    "Замещает": "Кавалерист",
                    "Сила": "34"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Уникальное здание": [
            {
                "image": "civStuffIcons/Австрия_Уникальное здание1.png",
                "Кофейня": {
                    "Замещает": "Мельница",
                    "Эффект": "+5% ед. продукции +2 ед. продукции Увеличивает на 25% ОВЛ скорость возникновения великих людей в городе.Может быть построена в любом городе."
                }
            }
        ],
        "Флаг": "civsFlags/austria.png"
    },
{
    "America":{
       ...
    }
}
```

data inside Resources: [image]

I need to loop through this file and, for example, get all country names(in this example it's "Austria","America")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist, get file "allCivs" ,then you must parse json "allCivs" and Find Countries

**Final Code**

```
string resxFile = @".\resources.resx";
List<string> _listCountry = new List<string>();
using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(resxFile))
{

 byte[] allCivs =(byte[]) resxSet.GetObject("allCivs");
 var texts = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(allCivs, 0, allCivs.Length);

var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(texts);
               
 foreach (var x in jsonObject)
 {
   _listCountry.Add(x.Key);
 }

}
```

Additional information

1.Way Solve Fist Problem ,you must change "Copy to output directory"  properties on file resources.resx

> 1.Right click resources.resx -> properties.
>
> 2.Change 'Copy to output directory' to "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer "

2.Read a key, you can use below code

```
  var Value = resxSet.GetString("allCivs");

 //using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse((string)resxSet.GetObject("Test")))
 //{
//    var d = "";
  //}
```

3.Read all of keys, you can use below code

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resxSet)
{
   string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
   object resource = entry.Value;
}
```

4.You can get List Country in json file with use below code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string text = File.ReadAllText(@"Test.json");
            var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(text);

            List<string> _list = new List<string>();
            foreach (var x in jsonObject)
            {
                _list.Add(x.Key);
            }
```

Comment: "allCivs" file is json, so when I use (string)resxSet.GetObject("allCivs")) I get an error, and when I use (FileStream)resxSet.GetObject("Test")) I also get an error. What class should i cast this object to?

Comment: all Civs is string(string json),you can serialize   json to other class c#,I edited my code and Add read all keys,with GetString you can get value

Comment: Perhaps, I texted something wrong, but "allCivs" is json file, and I need to read it. As I see  you thought that the "resxSet" is json and you go through it in a loop. But I need to loop through the "allCivs" json file

Comment: Unless "allCivs" is an item of the file resources.resx?Don't you have "allCivs" inside resources.resx?please show data "allCivs" and expected data

Comment: if you want read json in json file use this is code "string text = File.ReadAllText(@"./person.json");
        var person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(text)"

Comment: I added in question what you asked.
About your last comment. Do I need to create class Person? If yes, I think it's gonna be a bit difficult, because I have a lot of data in json file

Comment: As I understand .resx file is just a file which connected with some folder with resources, so there is nothing inside .resx file. Am I wrong?

Comment: ResX file in C# is an essential resource file format that is used to store localized strings, images, audio files, and other types of resources that are used in an application ,I edited my code (Final Code) based on Your Comment(include: Read " .resx file" or "allCivs"  and Find Country)